# Avoiding `sys.path.append(..)` for imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

This isn't the first time I am cringing over `imports` in Python. But I guess this one is an interesting use case, so I thought to ask it here to get a much better insight. The structure of my project is as follows:

```
sample_project
   - src
        - __init__.py
        - module1
           - __init__.py
           -  utils.py
        - module2
           - __init__.py 
           - models.py
        - app.py
```

The `module1` imports methods from `module2` and `app` imports method from all the other. Also, when you run the `app` it needs to create a folder called `logs` outside of `src` folder. There are now to ways to run the app:

1. From inside `src` folder `flask run app`
2. From outside of `src` folder `flask run src.app`

To make sure that I don't get `import errors` because of the change of the top level module where the app is started, I do this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

Is there any better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 16):

The **pythonic solution** for the import problem is to **not add sys.path** (or indirectly PYTHONPATH) **hacks** to any file that could potentially serve as top-level script (incl. unit tests), since this is what makes your code base difficult to change and maintain. Assume you have to reorganize your project structure or rename folders.

Instead this is what `editable installs` are made for. They can be achieved in 2 ways:

1. pip install --editable `<path>` (requires a basic setup.py)
2. conda develop `<path>` (requires the `conda-build` package)

Either way will add a symlink into your site-packages folder and make your local project behave as if it was fully installed while at the same time you can continue editing.

Always remember: KEEP THINGS EASY TO CHANGE

Answer (score 4):

After doing research ([here1](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-python-imports-init-py-and-pythonpath-once-and-for-all-4c5249ab6355), [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291608/effect-of-using-sys-path-insert0-path-and-sys-pathappend-when-loading-modul), [here3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267962/importing-modules-from-nested-folder), [here4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276154/how-to-write-nested-init-py-files), [here5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183205/importing-a-module-in-nested-packages), [here6](http://michaelgarrigan.com/blog/accessing_nested_files_python)), I come up with the better solution at this time. This is in each python file, you can add its current path before import. The example code below:

```
import os
import sys
if os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Python import system documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and at [the PYTHONPATH environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

When your code does `import X.Y`, what the Python runtime does is look in each folder listed in your `PYTHONPATH` for a package `X` (a package simply being a folder containing an `__init__.py` file) containing a `Y` package.

Most of the time, appending to `sys.path` is a poor solution. It is better to take care of what your PYTHONPATH is set to : check that it contains your **root** directory (which contains your **top-level** packages) and nothing else (except `site-packages` which i). Then, from wherever you run your commands, it will work the same (at least for imports, `os.cwd` is another problem).

Depending of the way to run your Python scripts, `.` may be the only relevant paths in it, so that it depends on your current directory, requiring to append `..` if you run it from inside one of your top-level package.

And maybe you should not run your scripts from a directory that is not the root of your project ?

TL;DR : a good `PYTHONPATH` makes for way less import errors.

Answer (score -1):

Wraps the `flask` command into a small script in the `sample_project` directory and set `PYTHONPATH` according to your project:

```sh
#!/bin/env bash

# Assuming script is sample_project
path=`dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`
full_path=`realpath "$p"`
export PYTHONPATH=$full_path/src:$PYTHONPATH

flask run app
```

You can also switch current directory to a working directory.

But it is best to package your project using `setuptools` and install it (possibly in [developpement mode](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html)), in user space according to [`PYTHONUSERBASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE) or in virtual environment.